# Recursive Many to many relationship with Yii

Tags: yii, many-to-many, gii, yii-cactiverecord, cactiverecord

I have a recursive many to many relationship with `objective`. My Relational model is:

```
CREATE TABLE master.objectives
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(100),
  CONSTRAINT pkey_objectives PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_objectives_perspective FOREIGN KEY (perspective_id)
      REFERENCES master.perspective (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE master.relatedobjectives
(
  parent integer NOT NULL,
  child integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT relatedobjectives_pkey PRIMARY KEY (parent, child),
  CONSTRAINT fk_child_objectives FOREIGN KEY (child)
      REFERENCES master.objectives (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_paret_objectives FOREIGN KEY (parent)
      REFERENCES master.objectives (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I have been generated my model in Yii framework with gii as shows belows:

**Objective.php**

```
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'parents' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Relatedobjectives', 'parent'),
        'children' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Relatedobjectives', 'child'),
    );
}
```

**objectives/_form.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <?= $form->checkBoxList($model,'parents', 
                            CHtml::listData(Objective::model()->findAll(array('order' => 'id')), 'id', 'name')
            ) ?>
</div>
```

In the view when I submit the form not save the relationship in relatedobjectives table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related models aren't saved along with the parent model. You must save them manually in the parents `beforeSave()` or `afterSave()` hooks. There are also some extensions which can do this automatically. Look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22148-how-to-save-related-objects/) for some info on that topic.